# How do we delete a stubborn cookie?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For a few months now we have been scratching our heads over how to delete a cookie that just doesnt want to delete.

The cookie gets set one of two ways, either from nodejs on initial oauth validation:

```js
// setCookie.js
const setCookie = (string, payload, milliSeconds, res) => {
  const headers = {
    // age
    maxAge: milliSeconds,
    // You can't access these tokens in the client's javascript
    httpOnly: false,
    // Forces to use https in production
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  }
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') headers.domain = '.my-prod-domain.com'
  // set the cookie
  res.cookie(string, payload, headers)
}

// ...

// within an expressJS route
// ...
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  // ...
  const NINETYDAYSASMS = (90 * 86400) * 1000
  setCookie('MYTOKEN', '1234567890', NINETYDAYSASMS, res)
  // ...
})
```

OR later the token gets updated when the oauth token expires and refreshed, the cookie is set from within the Javascript client UI on refresh

```js
// getAll.js
const getAll = () => {
  const pairs = document.cookie.split(';')
  const cookies = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    var pair = pairs[i].split('=')
    cookies[(pair[0] + '').trim()] = unescape(pair.slice(1).join('='))
  }
  return cookies
}

// get.js
const getCookie = token => {
  return getAll()[token]
} 

// delete.js
const deleteCookie = (name, domain = null) => {
  const cookie = getCookie(name)
  if (cookie) {
    let cookieString = `${name}=${cookie}`
    if (domain) cookieString += `;Domain=${domain}`
    // cookieString += `;max-age=0`
    const now = new Date()
    now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1)
    cookieString += `;expires=${now.toUTCString()}`
    cookieString += ';path=/'
    document.cookie = cookieString
  }
}

// deleteAll.js
const deleteAll = () => {
  var c = document.cookie.split(';')
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var e = c[i].indexOf('=')
    var n = e > -1 ? c[i].substr(0, e) : c[i]
    document.cookie = n + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'
  }
}

// set.js
const set = (key, value, seconds, domain) => {
  // delete existing instances of cookie before creating a new one
  deleteCookie(key, domain)
  // now its safe to set a new cookie
  let string = `${key}=${value}`
  if (seconds) string += `; max-age=${seconds}`
  if (domain) string += `; domain=${domain}`
  string += `; path=/`
  document.cookie = string
}
```

Setting the token from the UI on OAUTH token refresh

```js
const DOMAIN = '.my-prod-domain.com'
const NINETYDAYSASSECONDS = 90 * 86400
const token = '0987654321'
set('MYTOKEN', token, NINETYDAYSASSECONDS, process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? DOMAIN : null)
```

if the token fails to refresh, we run the following functions to kill existing cookies, but it seems to fail, the function runs the following:

```js
deleteCookie('MYTOKEN')
deleteAll()
```

the problem is that they work on local, but they dont seem to work on our production https site

any thoughts?

Comment: are you sure `const cookie = getCookie(name)` is getting the cookie? since you haven't shown what `getCookie` is

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad, went ahead and renamed the function that was supposed to be `getCookie`

Comment: looks like you create the cookie with domain `.my-prod-domain.com` - but you don't specify a domain when you're trying to delete it

Comment: there is no need to `getCookie(name)` in `deleteCookie` function, try removing it. Not all cookies are accessible to JS (see [restricting access to cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)). Also make sure exactly the same domain and path (as on server-side) are specified when deleting the cookie.

Comment: @Vitalii - code gets cookie to determine if it is present before "deleting" it - makes sense - if it's not accessible to JS, then you can't delete it with JS

Comment: @JaromandaX - you are likely correct on the domain issue, I ran a few tests in our production environment and it seems to work, holding out for a few more days until peoples tokens will expire to be sure